# python augmented assignment statements, display the results as per the output

Tags: python, augmented-assignment

Write a program which asks the user to enter an integer and then by using augmented assignment statements, display the results as per the output

```
Please enter the first integer: 5
Please enter the second integer: 4
5 + 4 is 9
5 - 4 is 1
5 * 4 is 20
5 / 4 is 1.25
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input("Enter the first integer: "))
b = int(input("Enter the second integer: "))
print(a, "+",b, "=", a+b)
print(a, "-",b, "=", a-b)
print(a, "*",b, "=", a*b)
print(a, "/",b, "=", a/b)
```